# Mount Azure file share

Tags: active-directory, azure-storage

I have created a public Azure file share and set the authentication method to Active Directory. The Azure storage account is domain joined to my on-premises Active Directory Domain Services. I have followed these steps to configure it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-active-directory-enable#overview

This is the file share and authentication method is set to Active Directory.

[image: Azure file share]

I have given access control to the user. The user also exist in on-premises Active Directory and is synced to Azure AD.

[image: Azure file share access control]

When I try to mount the file share, with the user's credentials, I get an access denied error.

I'm not sure what I'm missing or what to check to validate the access to the file share. Note: if I mount the file share using the access key it's working fine.

Comment: Hello , can you please try adding `Storage File Data SMB Share Reader/ Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor/ Storage File Data SMB Share Elevated Contributor` to that user for that file share as specified here in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-ad-ds-assign-permissions?tabs=azure-portal#share-level-permissions) ? as from the image i see that you have provided only contributor role to that user which is also inherited from subscription.  let me know if that resolved the issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments and also in this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems#cause-3-share-level-permissions-are-incorrect-when-using-identity-based-authentication) you need to provide the User which is present in both On-premises and Azure AD for the file share from one of the below roles as per you requirement:

> **`Storage File Data SMB Share Reader`** allows read access in Azure Storage
> file shares over SMB.
>
> **`Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor`** allows
> read, write, and delete access in Azure Storage file shares over SMB.
>
> **`Storage File Data SMB Share Elevated Contributor`** allows read, write,
> delete and modify NTFS permissions in Azure Storage file shares over
> SMB.

As per the image shared by you , your user has inherited the **`Contributor`** role for the resource from the **parent resource i.e. the Storage account** , that's why its giving you access denied error while mounting.